# 400 Bad Request from PUT to S3 using pre-signed URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, browser, xmlhttprequest, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a video file from JS to an S3 bucket but am getting a 400 bad request right now. I am sure I set up everything properly but could of done something.

I generate a URL on a server like this:

```
const client = new S3({
    accessKeyId: 'id-ommited',
    secretAccessKey: 'key-ommited',
    region: 'eu-west-2',
    useAccelerateEndpoint: true
});
const url = client.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket:  'screen-capture-uploads',
    Key:     'video.webm',
    Expires: 60 * 60,
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream'
});
```

This URL appears to be fine on my frontend which I put through to an XMLHttpRequest like so

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('PUT', body.url); // body.url being the presigned url
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.send(blob); // blob being the webm binary
```

I am using a CORS setup that just allows PUT from anywhere

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I checked that and it works fine.
Also the IAM user has permission to put to the bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::screen-capture-uploads/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I managed to solve my issues up to this point. I've looked at some other answers but didn't find anything useful for me. Anybody got any ideas for me?

Answer (score 4):

I went and got the endpoint it produced and just put it straight in the browser. Turns out I hadn't enabled transfer acceleration on the bucket I was using!

This just turned into a bad request without any extra information

Comment: S3 provides extra information in the response body.  `<Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>S3 Transfer Acceleration is not configured on this bucket</Message>...` but without transfer acceleration enabled, you probably wouldn't have gotten any CORS headers, either, so presumably the preflight check failed and the browser wouldn't give you the body.